# Rails Nested Model Form: Add nested model fields dynamically through JavaScript using Prototype

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype

I'm following a Railscast [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) from Jan 2010.

I'm implementing Project lists that has_many Items.

The code to dynamically add Item fields is not working.

#### views/projects/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <% f.fields_for :items do |builder| %>
    <%= render "item_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "+item", f, :items %></p>

  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

#### views/projects/_item_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="fields">
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name, "item" %>
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
</div>
```

#### helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end
  
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
  end
```

#### public/javascripts/application.js

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
  $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).up().insert({
    before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
  });
}
```

The original Jan 2010 code is available at https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-197/surveysays

The difference in the implementation is that my code only has 1 layer (Project / Item). The tutorial has more nesting (Survey / Question + Answer).

What do I need to change in the javascript or other parts to make the add new Item functionality work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The model needs to have accepts_nested_attributes_for declared in it.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Also, link_to_remote isn't in Rails 3 unless you install http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper first.